# Accessing cookie from another sub-domain

Tags: python, django, authentication, cookies

I have two django applications that are deployed at two different sub-domains, for example:

- data.mysite.com
- i.mysite.com

Both sites use the same django authentication framework and such, setting a cookie called `sessionid`. I can read the cookie from the current site using:

```
def my_view(request):
    # suppose this view is within the i.mysite.com application
    i_session_id = request.COOKIES['sessionid'] 
    data_session_id = ? # how to get this?
```

But then how could I grab the cookies from the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a shared authentication between your 2 subdomains then you need to set your session on `.mysite.com` domain. Then when you request to `data.mysite.com` will include this cookie, same for `i.mysite.com` domain. So, in settings.py:

```py
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=".mysite.com"
```

Comment: let's say I have two `sessionid`s set then. How would I grab both of them?

Comment: If you mean that in each django project you have a different cookie name then you should get those coolies by their names, that's it.
If you have the same cookie name in both projects that one will override another when set.